# Command to call shutdown-restart menu on Ubuntu Budgie 17.04?

Tags: shutdown, 17.04, budgie

I want to activate the shutdown menu with a keyboard combo on my Budgie desktop. What is the command to bring up the menu?

Comment: Close-voters: [Starting with 17.04, Ubuntu Budgie is an official derivative of Ubuntu and is on-topic for this site](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3):

Try: `gnome-session-quit --power-off`

Answer (score -2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> will bring up the shut down menu on many desktop environments, including KDE, MATE and Cinnamon.

Comment: Tried on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Unity, however) - no menu was brought up.

Comment: @kaz -- it works on Mate. DE and Cinnimon

Comment: @ravery Does it work on Budgie? (That's the DE the OP is asking about.)

Comment: @Eliah -- I don't have a Budgie, if it doesn't it can probably be enabled in the keyboard settings.